# Google Apps Script Tiggers events not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 4 triggers in Google Apps Script(see the image)

[image]

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA2");             
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");                  
 
function onOpen(e)  {
 range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: false}]);        
}
```

The problem I have is with the triggers: "runsies"  and "onOpen" that don't start at Spreedsheet open. The two triggers run perfectly manually.

I update with the what I use in Apps Script

Need some help please.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue of `The problem I have is with the triggers: "runsies" and "onOpen" that don't start at Spreedsheet open.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike. Very simple...the TRIGGERS with the name "runsies" and "onOpen" don't WORK when I open the Spreedsheet. It's only works when I RUN then manually.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue from `Very simple...the TRIGGERS with the name "runsies" and "onOpen" don't WORK when I open the Spreedsheet. It's only works when I RUN then manually.`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: We can not understand your situation and are unable to help you without sharing what you currently have. Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such as a copy/dummy spreadsheet with the script that you are using.

Comment: Where is the runsies function?

Comment: Please Explain `Tiggers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA2");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z" + sheet.getLastRow());
  range.sort([{ column: 1, ascending: false }]);
}
```